# Is it possible to make a form return with extra values attached to the text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a `json` field which holds the values of a `form`. What I would like to do is add some options to be attached to the value for post-processing. And I'd like them attached either in the form of an array or comma delimited string.

```
  <%= f.fields_for model_name do |mod| %>
    <% new_class.column_names.each do |col| %>
      <%= mod.fields_for "#{col}[]", col do |field| %>
        <%= field.label col %>
        <%= field.check_box col, value: "default_1 %>
        <%= field.check_box col, value: "default_2 %>
        <%= field.text_field col %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

So for a contrived example:

```
Pet.column_names #=> ["name"]
```

What I'd like to get back is something along the lines of

```
{pets: {
  name: "black, cat, Mr. Mistoffelees", # or ['black', 'cat', 'Mr. Mistoffelees'] also fine
  name: "dog, Barkers",
  name: "orange, Garfield",
  name: "Fido" # ["Fido"] again also fine
}
```

I can work with missing options using defaults, and the options are used once and thrown away and they're much more tightly bound to that particular `text_field` entry, and not the corresponding column value than the example would suggest.

Getting a hash back with the options could work as well if needed.

```
{pets: {
  name: {value: "Mr. Mistoffelees", options: ['black', 'cat']}
}
```

So, some progress changing the `fields_for` into

```
  <%= mod.label col %>
  <%= mod.collection_check_boxes "#{col}_opts", %w(val_1 val_2 ...), :to_s, :to_s %>
  <%= mod.text_field col %>
```

And then I just fix it before saving, but I would like to know what if anything can be done to add them directly from the form.

Comment: If I really understood what you say, how about adding hidden fields to the form that change dynamically on changing the value of `hstore`?

Comment: No, not hidden fields. I want the user to check a box for each option.

Comment: To match your last statement: `mod.fields_for "#{col}[options][]"`

Comment: No, doesn't work `'@product[properties][foos][id[options]' is not allowed as an instance variable name`. Or `undefined method `color' for "id":String` for the line with check box depending on implementation.